# Django Polls Tutorial with Voterid per choice stored

Tags: django, vote

Hi I have created the Django voting app with the tutorial. I am looking to add so that when loggedin user votes for a choice, the choice section is stored into db.
Models.py

```
class Choice(models.Model):
question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=400)
vote = models.IntegerField(default=0)
points = models.IntegerField(default=1)
def __str__(self):
    return self.choice_text


class Voter(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
selections = models.CharField( 'question.choice', max_length=600)
```

My Views.py and Vote.view:

```
class VoteView(generic.View):
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Getting current question
    question = get_object_or_404(Question,     pk=kwargs.get('question_id'))

    try:
        selected_choice =    question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Display flash message
        messages.error(request, "You didn't select a choice.")

        # Redirect to the current question voting form again
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('questionaire:detail', args=(kwargs.get('question_id'),)))
    else:
        selected_choice.vote += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        v = Voter(user=request.user, Question=q)
        v.save()
```

So I am trying to save the choices selected per users into the database, which will be stored for later processing and analysis.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `Question` and `Choice` to model `Voter` as `ForeignKey` fields.

You probably already have `Question` FK in `Voter` just didn't write it here.

Also, consider renaming your model from `Voter` to `Vote`